# How can I use odd even pseudo class for inner html?

Tags: css

I wanted to change position of `div.img-box` it is not working using below code. How do I do this?

```
<style>
  ul.home-grid-list li:nth-child (odd) div.img-box {float:left;}
  ul.home-grid-list li:nth-child (even) div.img-box {float:right;}
</style>

<ul class="home-grid-list">
            <li>
                <div class="img-box"><img src="images/h-grid-1.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="grid-info">                     
                    <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="img-box"><img src="images/h-grid-2.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="grid-info">
                    <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between `nth-child` and bracket.

It should be:

```
ul.home-grid-list li:nth-child(odd) div.img-box {float:left;}
ul.home-grid-list li:nth-child(even) div.img-box {float:right;}
```

**[Working DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/LxD9N/)**